Example of proof of an infimum?
I'm doing an excercise about infimums and supremums and I've seen different examples of proving a =inf(S) $\iff  a\le s :\forall s \in S, \forall \epsilon >0\exists s\in S\colon a+\epsilon>s$ and to me they just seem to be making it up like:
Let S := { $x+1, x\in (0,1)$}
Here the infimum is clearly 1 , so let's prove the hypothesis inf(S) = 1. Which means $1+\epsilon >x+1 $ for some $x \in (0,1)$.
Then it usually goes as, solving for x as scratchwork such that if $$ 
1+\epsilon < x_n +1 \implies x_n> \epsilon $$ Now, going backwards:
Given$$x_n>\epsilon \implies x_n +1 > \epsilon +1 $$
Then it is proven. However I fail to see how doing the same scratchwork for a different minimum for example $-2$
Scratchwork:
$$-2 +\epsilon < x_n +1 \implies x_n > \epsilon -3 $$
""Proof"":
Given $x_n > \epsilon -3 \implies x_n +1 > \epsilon -2 $
I believe my problem is with the bounds of x, since in the "proof" epsilon has to be at least 3 for a valid x to exist. But then I don't quite know how to express the $\forall\epsilon > 0 $ because in the correct proof the inequality is not valid for $\epsilon > 1 $

The infimum is the largest lower bound. Just because you have found a lower bound does not mean that it is the infimum.

Your definition is not complete, it also requiert that $a\leq s$ for all $s\in S$.


$1$ is indeed an lower bound, since for all $x+1\in S$ applies $$x+1>1$$
$1$ is the largest lower bound, i.e. for every $\epsilon>0$ exists some $s\in S$ with $$1+\epsilon>s.$$ We can choose $s:=1+\frac\epsilon2\in S$.
$-1$ is not the largest lower bound. Choose $\epsilon=\frac12$. Assume there is some $s\in S$ with $$-1+\epsilon>s.$$ This yields $-\frac12>s$, but every element of $S$ is non-negative. Contradiction.

The general case:
Let $a<1$. We want to prove that $a\neq \inf(S)$. Choose $\epsilon=\frac{1-a}2>0$
$$a+\epsilon=a+\frac{1-a}2=\frac{1+a}2<\frac{1+1}{2}=1.$$ But every Element of $S$ is at least $1$.
For $a>1$, $a$ is obviously not a lower bound.

How should i choose $\epsilon$  for other cases?

I added a general case:)

Thank you, I think I've got it now
